# Difficulties causing html div to slide horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having trouble animating this item using PHP and CSS and Javascript (with jQuery).
I want a div that slides out from the left side of the screen when its tab bar is hovered over.
I have three divs: the container, the contents, and the tab.

Here's the Javascript and HTML:

```
<div id="LeftSidebar">
    <div id="LeftSidebarTab" class="">
        Left sidebar tab
    </div>
    <div id="LeftSidebarContents" class="">
        Left sidebar contents
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#LeftSidebar").mouseenter(function()
        {
                $("#LeftSidebar").animate(
            {
                    left: 0px
            });
        });

        $("#LeftSidebar").mouseleave(function()
        {
                $("#LeftSidebar").animate(
            {
                    left: -100px
            });
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#LeftSidebar
{
    position: absolute;
    display: block;

    z-index: 12;
    top: 220px;
    left: 0px;

    background-color: green;

    height: 500px;
}

#LeftSidebarTab
{
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 100%;
}

#LeftSidebarContents
{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I'm new to Javascript, HTML, and et al.

The code isn't doing what I expect it to do.
I expect it to, when hovered over, gradually move the 'left' CSS property to 0px, and when the mouse moves off of the contents, move the 'left' CSS property to -100px.

When I hover over it, I see no visible change to the div. I can't even tell if the 'mouseenter()' or 'mouseleave()' functions are even being triggered.

Questions:
1) How can I check if the function is being triggered or not? Can I output some text or something, using Javascript? Maybe pop up a dialog box for debugging?

2) Will mouseenter/mouseleave be triggered for 'LeftSidebar', even though LeftSidebarContents and LeftSidebarTab completely cover every pixel of LeftSidebar?

3) Am I making any obvious mistakes in the above code that's causing it not to work as I expect?

Comment: You may want to use Firefox with the firebug extension. Then you can change the css values and see what happens. But, the left of Leftsidebar = 0 normally, and you want to move it -100px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to put some single quotes around the 0px.

Check this: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Copy their example and get theirs working them modify it to your needs.

As for alerts to check if the event is being triggered:

```
 alert("Thanks for visiting!");
```

Comment: Also have you definitely got the jQuery library included in the HTML document?

Comment: Yes, jQuery is definitely included. Thanks, this helped. The alert()s showed that the javascript wasn't even being triggered - and Google Chrome's debugging gave a very generically stated "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL" without telling me which token was the illegal one. *rolls eyes* After spending a day trying to figure out whether I have non-visible ASCII characters accidentally mixed in my plaintext file, I re-read your answer again, and realized I was still missing the single quotes - I must have missed that the first time around.

Answer (score 1):

Use ff with firebug or chrome to debug your script. Put a pointer on the functions, this will cause the browser to pauze execution of your script so you can step over it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty test to figure out if an event is being triggered is to use the alert function. For example:

```
    $("#LeftSidebar").mouseenter(function()
    {
         alert("Mouse Enters Region");
    });
```

Also this is how I would do your css file:

```
#LeftSidebar
{
    position: fixed;  
    display: block;

    z-index: 12;
    top: 220px;
    left: -100px;

    background-color: green;
    width:120px;
    height: 500px;
}

#LeftSidebarTab
{
    position:absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 500px;
    left:100px;
    top:0px;
}

#LeftSidebarContents
{
    background-color: blue;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

I would recommend learning more about the CSS Box Model and probably just reading up on HTML/CSS in general.